# How to create a JDBC DB2 database connection URL if your database has no username or password? Getting error when fields are left blank

Tags: database, jdbc, spring-boot, db2, database-connection

This is the driver I am using `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

The jar is `db2jcc4.jar`

I'm doing this for my connection url:
`jdbc:db2://servername:50000/pscf:;` and it gives a `null userid is not supported` error. I also tried it without a colon before the semicolon and it gives a `Invalid database URL syntax: ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815` error.

The database I am connecting to has no username or password. I tried putting in empty values for the fields user and password and that also errored.

This probably doesnt matter but I'm using Spring Boot and this connection info is in my properties file.

Comment: I'm using spring boot and I'm simply trying to connect to this database. I think it might be a driver issue, do you know if there is a  db2 driver that doesnt require username and password

Comment: Tried with ":user=;:password=;" ?

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Why do you think that you don't need to use a username and password? Is the database server the same machine your Java app is running on?

Comment: Who is administrating that database? Every DB2 database has a username/password.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909092/user-and-password-when-connecting-to-db2-via-jdbc